# Flickr oAuth signing requests

Tags: oauth, signature, flickr

Flickr started to support oAuth just few weeks ago and there is no up to date documentation.. I was able to pass oAuth authentication process but I am unable to upload a photo through API.

I am supposed to sign all parameters except photo parameter. This is my signature base:

> POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Fupload%2F&oauth_consumer_key%3D...6b%26oauth_nonce%3D90660%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-HA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1309888296%26oauth_token%3D72157626975786735-ed7eccb40ffcc69e%26oauth_version%3D1.0d

And I use "consumer_secret&token_secret" to sign it.

It's all written in AS3 with oAuth library but I think it doesn't matter. The response I get is:

"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"

I don't think there is a problem with API key..

Any suggestions guys??
Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify your question: is your "oauth_consumer_key" preceeded by "&" (as in your original question), or by "?" (as in your July 6 posting)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the incorrect Path.  The latest Oauth docs are here:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

you can learn more about signing requests here:

http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/

and I'm not sure what language you're using but here is an example in Ruby:

https://gist.github.com/383159

and Python:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120919234615/http://mkelsey.com/2011/07/03/Flickr-oAuth-Python-Example.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already gone through authentication. Now I want to upload a photo:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html
After some testing it looks like the signature is correct. The problem si somewhere in my post request.. Does anyone have a working example of posting data with HTTP POST? I am using Actionsript 3..

Comment: GOT IT!!! I had extra "/" in the url:http://api.flickr.com/services/upload"/"?oauth_consumer_key Let's the uploading begin :)

Comment: rotten link for python.